# Sum $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I have the following infinite sum:
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}
$$
Because there is a $(-1)^n$ I deduce that it is a alternating series.
Therefore I use the alternating series test:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}
$$
Because this limit is decreasing and approaching $0$ I thought it should therefore be convergent. However in the answer key it uses a different method to get a different answer. It instead takes the absolute value of the series:

$\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and says because this is a divergent p series that the series is divergent.

Why is the alternating series test not applied here?

Comment: Ohhhhh. Okay. I thought I was going crazy, the answer key does indicate that it is not absolutely convergent. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that the series is convergent, for the reasons you indicated. The answer key is checking for *absolute* convergence. The series is convergent, but not absolutely convergent. In other words, it is conditionally convergent.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over \root{n}}} =
\lim_{N \to \infty}\,\sum_{n = 1}^{N}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over \root{n}}
\\[5mm] = & \
\lim_{N \to \infty}\bracks{%
\sum_{n = 1}^{\left\lfloor\,{N/2}\,\right\rfloor}{1 \over \root{2n}} - \pars{\sum_{n = 1}^{N}{1 \over \root{n}} -
\sum_{n = 1}^{\left\lfloor\,{N/2}\,\right\rfloor}{1 \over \root{2n}}}}
\\[5mm] = & \
\lim_{N \to \infty}\pars{%
\root{2}\sum_{n = 1}^{\left\lfloor\,{N/2}\,\right\rfloor}{1 \over \root{n}} - \sum_{n = 1}^{N}{1 \over \root{n}}}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
With [a Riemann Zeta Identity](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.2.E8):
\begin{align}
& \sum_{n = 1}^{m}{1 \over \root{n}}
\\ = & \ 2\root{m} + \zeta\pars{1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2}\int_{m}^{\infty}\!\!{\braces{x} \over x^{3/2}}\,\dd x \!\!\sr{{\rm as}\ m\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}
\bbx{2\root{m} + \zeta\pars{1 \over 2}}
\end{align}
This identity and (\ref{1}) lead to:
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over \root{n}}}
\\ = & \ \lim_{N \to \infty}\braces{\root{2}\bracks{2\root{\left\lfloor\,{N \over 2}\,\right\rfloor} + \zeta\pars{1 \over 2}} -
\bracks{2\root{N} + \zeta\pars{1 \over 2}}}
\\[5mm] = & \ \bbx{\color{#44f}{\pars{\root{2} - 1}\zeta\pars{1 \over 2}}} \approx -0.6049 \\ &
\end{align}
Note that $\ds{\lim_{N \to \infty}\pars{2\root{2}\root{\left\lfloor\,{N \over 2}\,\right\rfloor} - 2\root{N}} = \color{red}{\Large0}}$.